# SenTestKit is not found Error in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, file-not-found

I just started developing an ios app and I got the error:

```
'SenTestKit/SenTestingKit.h' file not found
```

and then it failed the build. I looked in the frameworks folder and it wasn't there. I am not sure if I am looking in the wrong place or if it really isn't there. I downloaded the newest version of xcode from the app store. I thought that was supposed to be included. Anyways, where would I find it if I do have it and if I don't have it, where can I download it. By the way I need to keep it legal, so no downloading copyrighted files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SenTestKit is a framework provided by apple. You can add framework as shown in image.

1. Tap on your project as shown in steps 1 in image.
2. Tap Build Phases
3. In "Link with Binary Section", you need to tap + button and a  list of frameworks will come in drop down. Just find which ever you need.

For this you just need to choose SenTestKit from the list.

/[image]